# Bluetooth-- Blueman Assisstant ( No Adapters found)

Tags: networking, 18.04, bluetooth, blueman

I got a new **Bluetooth USB adapter** and connected to my **PC** (no a laptop) working with **Ubuntu 18.04**. My computer does not have any bluetooth device in it, so I bought a bluetooth adapter.

When I connect the Bluetooth USB I get the Blutooth sign on the top right side of the screen but I cannot connect it to any device. When I click "**Setup a new device**" it gives me a massage of "**Blueman Assisstant ( No Adapters found)**". I check the Blueman-Assistant but I cannot have any options to click there. 
I went through a lot of websites and similar cases in this website, but I couldn't fix my problem.
I hope you guys will guide to fix this issue.

Thank you in advance

---

Here is the results of the `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9500 [Galaxy S4] / GT-I9250 [Galaxy Nexus] (network tethering)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 09da:f613 A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Results of `usb-devices` command:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 8
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.15
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.15.0-101-generic ehci_hcd
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1d.7
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#= 14 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=04e8 ProdID=6863 Rev=ff.ff
S:  Manufacturer=SAMSUNG
S:  Product=SAMSUNG_Android
S:  SerialNumber=5203b6535fe7c37d
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=96mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=03 Driver=rndis_host
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=rndis_host

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=12  MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0001 Rev=04.15
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.15.0-101-generic uhci_hcd
S:  Product=UHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1d.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=03 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=12  MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0001 Rev=04.15
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.15.0-101-generic uhci_hcd
S:  Product=UHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1d.1
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0a12 ProdID=0001 Rev=75.58
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb

T:  Bus=04 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=12  MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0001 Rev=04.15
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.15.0-101-generic uhci_hcd
S:  Product=UHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1d.2
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=05 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=12  MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0001 Rev=04.15
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.15.0-101-generic uhci_hcd
S:  Product=UHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1d.3
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=05 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=09da ProdID=f613 Rev=99.00
S:  Manufacturer=COMPANY
S:  Product=USB Device
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid
```

outputs of `dmesg | grep -i blue` command:

```
[  345.816078] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  345.816109] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  345.816113] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  345.816116] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  345.816121] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  347.146267] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  347.146269] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  347.146274] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  348.006358] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2003 tx timeout
[  350.048061] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2007 tx timeout
[78254.912688] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2003 tx timeout
[78256.960701] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2007 tx timeout
```

Comment: Hey, my question is that how can I fix the problem with bluetooth.

Comment: @V3N0M Please **edit** your posts next time and add details.  Do not post output as comments, as it loses formatting and isn't readable.

Comment: Please also add output of `usb-devices` to your question with the USB adapter plugged in. And also add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`. We need to identify the adapter.

Comment: The first `lsusb` is useless. It was run without the dongle inserted. I will edit the question and leave only relevant information.

Comment: Guys, thank you for your feedback. I edited things that you asked and put the outputs of the command. Sorry for inconvenient, I'm new hear, just learning and will improve. thanks

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: You were right,I run the "lsusb"  command and edited the output in the question.

Comment: Guys did you find any solutions?